# Redux-observable with async method

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, rxjs6, redux-observable

I am trying to implement Observables with react/redux with async actions, here is the code of my epic, so far everything works properly:

```
export function requestDataEpic (action$, store) {    
   return action$.pipe(
     ofType(REQUEST_DATA),
     mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
        return Observable.ajax.get(`${API_URL}/${payload.userId}`)
          .flatMap((result) => {
             return Observable.of(requestDataSucess({ result }))
           })
           .catch((error) => {
             return Observable.of(requestDataFailure({ error }))
           })
     }
   ),
   catchError((error) => {      
     alertError({ error })
     return empty()
   })
  )
}
```

This works perfectly as expected.

Now, the problem happens when I try to call my getData function (which performs an async call) instead of directly calling `Observable.ajax.get`. I would like to call this function which would verify the API token and then process the `Observable.ajax` call such as:

```
export default async function getData ({ URL, userId }) {
  const { token } = await verifyToken()

  const params = {
    token,
    userId,
  }

  const query = Object.keys(params)
    .map((key) => key + '=' + params[key])
    .concat(fields)
    .join('&')

  return Observable.ajax.get(URL + query)
}
```

So the final code would look like this:

```
export function requestDataEpic (action$, store) {    
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(REQUEST_DATA),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
      return getData(API_URL, payload.userId)
        .flatMap((result) => {
          return Observable.of(requestDataSucess({ result }))
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return Observable.of(requestDataFailure({ error }))
        })
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      alertError({ error })
      return empty()
    })
  )
}
```

I get

> (getData.default)(...)flatMap is not a function

If I remove the async word in the function declaration + remove the `await verifyToken()`, then it works again.

There are things I don't fully understand, I can not turn everything into Observable, I need to keep using async stuff.

Any help would be awesome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I can not turn everything into Observable, I need to keep using async stuff.

You actually can and you should to convert anything to an observable in the end. `flatMap` doesn't exist on a promise, therefore there's the error.

`getData` doesn't make sense because it mixes promises and observables and returns a promise of an observable. One of them has to be chosen, e.g:

```
async function getData ({ URL, userId }) {
  const { token } = await verifyToken()
  ...
  return Observable.ajax.get(URL + query).toPromise()
}
```

Promises can be converted to observables with `mergeMap`/`switchMap` operators or `from`. There's no need to use `flatMap` if you're already using promises:

```
   return action$.pipe(ofType(REQUEST_DATA),
     mergeMap(async ({ payload }) => {
       try {
         const result = await Observable.ajax.get(`${API_URL}/${payload.userId}`).toPromise();
         return requestDataSucess({ result });
       } catch (error) {
         return requestDataFailure({ error });
       }
     })
   })
```

Comment: A non-serializable value was detected in an action

Comment: This means that the result wasn't processed correctly. In the code above it depends on how `requestDataSucess` works. The snippet missed `toPromise`, it was fixed. If the problem persists, consider asking a question that reflects your problem.

Comment: When I pass an async function to mergeMap, I receive this error. When I remove the async, everything works. But I need an async function, because I use AsyncStorage